# What is this 11-engine airplane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]

I thought it looked similar to an [An-225](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-225_Mriya), but there are too many engines.

Comment: It's a fake one. What's the image source? Add it please.

Comment: Please make some basic research before posting here. Auch aircraft only exists in fiction

Answer (score 4):

That frame comes from a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPdi3iEC_KY) showing that "plane" crashing. The plane and video are faked. If a giant 11-engined airplane had existed, it would have been popular. And even more so if it was filmed crashing.

Comment: The video was uploaded by a user named "Faik Enigma" which is a clue.